# hello, How to combine these two vi labview files together?

Tags: labview

I have this car project of 3 Gauges ( RPM, temperatue, and fuel) , RPM and fuel are working together , and fuel code is working alone , i just need some help to combine the all together, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, merging VIs is difficult to impossible through automatic means.  You will have to copy the code manually if you want it all in the same VI.

However, there are ways to view VIs in a subpanel.  You would want to move to a more advanced architecture to really get the benefit.  Here are a few links to help get you started.  I hope this helps!

- [Programming Elements](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/Programming_Elements)
- [Insert VI into SubPanel](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/SubPanel_class/Insert_VI_method)
- [Run VI](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/VI_class/Run_VI_method)